# How is the thread_local keyword implemented?

Tags: c++

I know that Windows and Pthreads have their own TLS API but what I'm asking is how the thread_local keyword is implemented in the C++ compiler (or does it simply call these Windows/Pthreads API?).

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847552/c-where-are-thread-local-variables-stored/45849265#45849265) about a table of slots in each thread but I still don't really understand it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: The details will vary from compiler to compiler and operating system to operating system.

Comment: The compiler has to do extra work in addition to the functions in the OS API's. Neither Windows nor pthreads understand C++ types. Hence, even on the same OS, using the same OS functions, different compilers can make different choices.